# Editing post with same tag multiple times

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Today, when I was reviewing suggested edits, I found a user, [gaurav-dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4414557/gaurav-dave?tab=reputation), who suggested lots of suggestions with the comment 'added an important tag', and all tags were the same, [jenssegers-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenssegers-mongodb), and he did not edit anything else. Here is a list of suggestions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8000627
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8000707
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8000742
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8000745
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8000699
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8000715
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8000641
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8000706

I could not understand he is doing spam or the suggestion is right. And all the suggestions were coming one after one when I was doing review tasks. I skipped all. But what should I do if I find such type of the same suggestion?

**Note**: When I am going for the next suggestion I find lots of suggestions from that user. It's hard to list all the suggestions.

Comment: Typically mass edits like this aren't good to do without community approval first, and even if it was approved of, the user should be improving the posts besides editing the tag in.

Comment: Yes, that tag is useful and most of the question were lagging that tag, that's the reason why I added them. They are not span.

Comment: @GauravDave Care to explain why that tag was important and meaningful? Just saying that a tag is useful doesn't make it so. You could post an answer to this question...

Comment: @GauravDave That's great, you've got a legit explanation - but post it as an actual answer (then delete your comment).

Comment: @Guaurav, it would be nice to address all other problems with the question when editing also.

Comment: @JonasCz Sure, I love doing that. But sometime you happen to have a bad day and can't help coders, but anyways I sure will!

Comment: I think edits like this should be possible. They can improve the value of a post. And I find Gaurav Dave's answer plausible. However, since those edits are so simple and almost automated, there should not be a reward, i.e. no step further to a certain badge. Actually from time to time I see little things I'd like to correct, e.g. a typo, but I don't do it, because: "Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged." and I am not **the** editor, who can make a diffenrce. So the typo remain. There should be an option to do stuff like that 'for free', but therefore with less scrutiny.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package on GitHub, named [jessengers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB) and which is used for integration of [Laravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel) with [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB). This package is very popular and in every question you can see them talking about that package.

So, I found out since there is no tag related to it. I created that tag, that will help a coder to just use the tag and don't have to tell again aand again what and why a package is been used. Even currently I'm using that package for my hobby project.

Comment: What about posting links to tutorials (on Youtube) in tag wikis, and also pasting content from other sources? I know that the second is not good, as there is an Edit Review reject reason. I doubt that the first is useful either, the things would get stuffed with everyone posting their favourite links, even if all were well-intentioned.

Comment: Adding a useful tag(I'm not saying its useful) is all well and good, but you should do more than simply edit the tag in; on posts where there are other things to fix, you should fix those things as well as adding the tag.  However, I also fall back to my earlier comment; this mass of edits you did would have been better if you asked for approval first on this sub-site(meta, where we are now).

Comment: @BillWoodger Well, I know that if you visit some famous tags like php, java etc you do get good source but sometime a newbie just want to access a simple tutorial and when I was learing those languages I founded them good and that's the reason why I added them and my Intentions are good.

Comment: @Daedalus I didn't know that there is any approval system, otherwise I would have done that. Next time I will take that into consideration, and Thanks for showing me right path.

Comment: @GauravDave I'm blaming the reviewers that those things got through. When editing the wikis for a tag, content is not supposed to be copied (if it were, then they'd just link to the data elsewhere). You can't put things like tutorials in, as if you do that you then get 900 tutorials and daily spam attempts and the wikis would be useless.

Comment: @BillWoodger Sure, I will take that into consideration.

Comment: @BillWoodger, that's true however the slackness that is encouraged by saying any edit that improves the post in any way is valid is really the problem. I do agree that it's been a problem for a bit but it's an inheritance problem at this point. It's perpetual because time is spent earning rep by doing incorrect things until enough rep is given to pass it on to others. The fact you can edit a post to include a single tag and giving rep to do it is insanity to me.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I don't see how that lets links to videos (is reviewer going to check the video for spam, the whole video? No? So reject, reject-and-edit if there is some good stuff as well) and copied content (which has a specific reject reason) through .

Comment: @BillWoodger, I was just making a statement about the review "culture". It allows videos to "get through" because a user can't review an edit properly if they don't know, or care, what a proper edit *is*. The wiki tag page says those with enough rep get random tag suggested edits. The question I'm posing is are they treated any differently? It's obvious when spending some time in the queues there's far too many edits being approved. It's true that they are to blame but only after those who "trained" them it was right. That was the point. Perhaps I missed yours.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils have you got a handy link for the "random tag suggested edits", please? There is no training, as you know, and how would it be done? It is common-sense that a video could contain anything, even if the first 20 seconds/however long are relevant to a particular tag. Tutorials, in their nature, are often promoting training/services/the site itself for Ad revenue. I don't know if creating/editing wikis warns against copying, but there's a prominent rejection reason - if the reviewer has ever bothered to click on Reject to see what is available.

Comment: @BillWoodger, [sure](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits). I'm speaking in code I suppose. The training you get is feedback from upper rep users in the form of accepted edits. IOW, because others approve edits inconsistently if not all-together incorrectly, the editor in turn gets to review edits in the future under this continuing misunderstanding. So, I'm not disagreeing with your thoughts on videos and content. I guess to get to the point would be - yes it's the reviewer's issue but it's a community problem. That seemed pretty non-descriptive though.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thanks for the link. I'd not realised I had new powers over tag-wiki edits, I had just thought that there was a mass-proliferation and with the change to the edit reviews (locking) that I was now seeing what had previously been rapidly accepted :-) Edit reviews had been so futile I'd stopped reviewing for many months so I went over 5000 when not reviewing. I reject most of the ones I see for copied content.