# Selective retagging [dbi] to [r-dbi]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, suggested-edits

I'm starting to edit more, and would like some guidance before I start something unproductive or waste someone's time.

The [DBI](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=DBI) package for R is gaining a lot of momentum, and I see [60 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+dbi) tagged with [r] and [dbi].  The vast majority should have used the [`[r-dbi]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-dbi) tag (that refers to the R package) instead of the [`[dbi]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) tag (that refers to the Perl module).

Is it helpful if I modify these tags to [r-dbi]?

1. @daedalus suggested that ["Typically mass (tag) edits aren't good to do without community approval first"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293803/editing-post-with-same-tag-multiple-times?rq=1#comment190894_293803).  Is this current stack overflow meta question the proper was to get community approval?
2. Since I have fewer than 2,000 points, my edits require two additional people to approve; is this burden more than it's worth?  @ChrisF stated ["It might be better to hold off the "simple" retags until you reach 2k"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290913/1082435).
3. Multiple sources expressed roughly ["please review the whole question and see if there's anything else you can improve"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290913/1082435) (besides the tag edits).  Realistically, I don't think I'll make the time to closely read the 60 questions and make thoughtful edits.  But I do think it's realistic for me to tackle a few [dbi]/[r-dbi] modifications occasionally and get to all 60 in a few days.  Is this still a useful contribution? The Perl developers searching [dbi] won't be polluted with R questions, and the R developers searching [r-dbi] see a better range of questions.
4. To feel out the situation, I've already made five [dbi] -> [r-dbi] retags, and the [current reviews have approved the edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1082435/wibeasley?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).  So it looks like there's at least some support for this retag.
5. Any  things else I should be considering?

Two more (or of a dozen) retagging references (involving point 2):

- [How to deal with serial tag-only edits from Sub 2k users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314488/how-to-deal-with-serial-tag-only-edits-from-sub-2k-users)
- [Mass trivial tag-only edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367446/mass-trivial-tag-only-edits?rq=1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Asking the question here on MSO gets the attention of people who can help.  I'm the principal author of the Perl DBD::Informix module which is used by the Perl DBI module for connecting to Informix databases, so I have what might be termed a vested interest in keeping the Perl [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) tag clean.  I also have slightly more than 2k accrued reputation.

Consequently, I've gone through the list of questions tagged with both [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) and approved (by improving) those edits that were pending review, and by editing the tags for the others.

- There are currently no questions with both the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag and the [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) tag.

The questions as a whole surprised me; there were few additional edits needed on most of them apart from the retagging, certainly by comparison with other sets of questions I've gone through on retagging exercises.  With Firefox on a Mac, I find that having `r-dbi`  (with a space after the `i`) in my paste buffer, and using Firefox's remembered text entry facility (I type 'r' in the edit description; it offers 'Replace Perl DBI tag with the R DBI tag'), it was relatively painless to make the changes.

It is better, in general, to wait until you have the necessary reputation to make the changes without troubling the review queues.  Until then, asking on MSO and attracting the attention of people who can make the changes is sensible.

Comment: love the understatement!