# Situation around [dbi] and [r-dbi]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

We have tag [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi). Its excerpt clearly states not to use it for questions about the R package:

> DBI is a database access module for the Perl programming language. It defines a set of methods, variables, and conventions that provide a consistent database interface, independent of the actual database being used. For the equivalent R package, use the tag r-dbi.

But there are [241 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi+r) tagged with [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) and [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r). And this is a very similar number to 267 questions tagged with [r-dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-dbi).

In the interest of keeping our tags in order, we should probably make some effort to clean this mess up.

It seems like we have two possible general directions:

1. Retag every question which has [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)[dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) with [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)[r-dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-dbi) (and apply some additional curation to other [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) questions that aren't tagged with [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl), like the pair [[ruby][dbi]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby+dbi) with creation of [ruby-dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-dbi)). And after [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) is only related to the Perl library, rename it into [perl-dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-dbi) to avoid confusion and repetition of the same situation in the future. It will result in a clear segregation of questions, but it will require manual retagging of 241 questions (+111 of neither Perl, nor R ones).
2. Merge [r-dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-dbi) into [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) and allow for these kind of questions to be searched only by `[r][dbi]`. Since almost all [r-dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-dbi) questions (except for 9) are simultaneously tagged with [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), this process is almost fully automated, but it blurs the lines between different libraries and may introduce some confusion.

I'm not familiar with either of the libraries, so it would be very helpful to hear from [SMEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert) about the similarity (or lack thereof) of those libraries and reasonableness of a tags merge.

Additionally, there is the fact that the [R Collective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423429/launching-the-ci-cd-and-r-collectives-and-community-editing-features-for-article) exists: tag [r-dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-dbi) can theoretically be included into collective (though it is not now). And if we will go with the second option, the collective will lose that ability, and will need to rely on other question tags. I don't think it matters much, but in the interest of transparency of the discussion, I decided to mention anyway.

Also, there is this question: [Selective retagging [dbi] to [r-dbi]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369627/selective-retagging-dbi-to-r-dbi). It didn't explicitly asked for community's opinion, but more asked for permission to extract a smaller batch of [r-dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-dbi) questions from [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi), thus we can't draw any conclusions other than it was only upvoted, so probably no obvious objections.

I invite everybody involved in curation to discuss this matter and help to decide what approach should be adopted regarding this situation.

Comment: See also [\[ruby\]\[dbi\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby+dbi) and [\[dbi\] -\[perl\] -\[ruby\] -\[r\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi+-perl+-ruby+-r)

Comment: Isn't it better to rename `dbi` tag to `perl-dbi`, so it would never be used for non-Perl questions? The fact that for some languages the tag name has a language-prefix, but for other languages doesn't looks weird.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, probably it will be logical outcome if we select way #1. But before that we should re-tag all incorrectly tagged (r-)dbi questions.

Comment: I would certainly include renaming it (and creating any other ones needed, like [ruby-dbi]) in option #1.  Otherwise it'll keep happening.

Comment: There were 10 questions dual-tagged with [tag:dbi] and [tag:r-dbi] (and each of them was also tagged with [tag:r]).  None of those questions is still tagged with [tag:dbi].

Comment: Option 1 is definitely preferable to my way of thinking.  I'm biassed inasmuch as I wrote one of the Perl DBI drivers (DBD::Informix), but the [tag:dbi] should be used only for Perl-related DBI questions; questions related to other languages should be retagged.  I think that renaming the tag to [tag:perl-dbi] makes a lot of sense, once it is clean of questions unrelated to Perl.  I don't particularly like the idea of the plain tag [tag:dbi] being redrafted for any use — the language-qualified tags should be used exclusively.

Comment: There's also [tag:jdbi] for Java, which may or may not be related.

Comment: Why rename `dbi` to `perl-dbi`? Why not treat it like the `sql` tag and also have the poster tag the relevant language? So posts correctly tagged as `dbi` can be `perl`, `dbi` and then the others can be `r`, `dbi`. I'm not familiar with `dbi` at all, so I could absolutely be missing the reason multiple individual tags would be relevant.

Comment: @markalex oh I'm aware, I meant in regards to all of the comments supporting the other option.

Comment: @Austin: as I noted [below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426039/situation-around-dbi-and-r-dbi/426068?noredirect=1#comment969637_426068), the various libraries with DBI in the name are almost wholly unrelated to each other — they just provide a database interface in the different languages.  A generic DBI tag is not useful.  The Perl [tag:dbi] and [tag:dbd] tags have primacy solely because of age (dbi @ 14y 11m; dbd @ 14y 9m; r-dbi @ 8y 7m); they should be renamed to [tag:perl-dbi] and [tag:perl-dbd] once the Perl [tag:dbi] tag is clean of non-Perl questions.

Comment: I'd forgotten that I'd done the R and DBI ([tag:dbi] to [tag:r-dbi]) cleanup in [Selective retagging dbi to r-dbi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369627/selective-retagging-dbi-to-r-dbi) in June 2018.  And I haven't been keeping an eye on additions made in the last 5 years.  Can you still subscribe to tags, getting notifications when questions arrive?  I have 3 existing subscriptions but couldn't see a way to create new ones.

Comment: Reminder that if you have an opinion on what you think should happen, and you haven't posted it as an answer or voted for existing answer(s), you should do that: answer voting is how we generally determine the resolutions for things like this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler makes sense, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 5):

I just did a query `[dbi] -[perl]` (questions tagged with [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) and not tagged with [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl)); there are 337 such questions.

Of those, 231 are tagged with [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) — those should be retagged, replacing [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) with [r-dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-dbi).

Another 59 are tagged with [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) — those should be retagged, replacing [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) with the (to be created) [ruby-dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-dbi).

The remaining 47 questions require a diverse range of fixes.  Some need to be tagged with [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) too.  Some are already tagged with [jdbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdbi) and should have the [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) tag removed.  Most of these are not hard to fix.

Once this cleanup is complete, we can request a tag rename from [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) to [perl-dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-dbi).  Then the plain [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) tag is eliminated, and it should not be recreated.  Newcomers to the site can't create tags; people who've been around for a while shouldn't create it and may know better.

I note that the tag [dbd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbd) is the complementary tag to [dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dbi) for the Perl database drivers.  Presumably, it should be renamed to [perl-dbd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-dbd) for symmetry, and the affected questions also retagged by the renaming process.

The tag wiki entries will need to be updated (and created for [ruby-dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-dbi)).

---

**About Ruby DBI**

*Some of this information might be useful in a tag wiki for the suggested [ruby-dbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-dbi) tag.*

One version of the Ruby DBI seems to be available from GitHub (https://github.com/Pistos/ruby-dbi) — the other repo referenced doesn't exist any more (https://github.com/erikh/ruby-dbi).  The code appears to have been last updated in September 2009.  The README.md file describes it like this (give or take a couple of editorial changes I just made):

> The DBI package is a vendor-independent interface for accessing databases. It is similar, but not identical, to Perl's DBI module.

There might be other, more recent repos for this package — I didn't stress my Google (or GitHub) searching beyond "ruby dbi".

Comment: Can you as an expert also provide some insight into relations between this libraries in different languages? I mean if this is the same library with different wrappers - it's analogous to [tag:sql], and I see second option as more valid. But if those are different libraries, that just so happened share the same name, solution you selected is obviously better.

Comment: AFAIK, the R DBI is wholly unrelated to the Perl DBI, and the Ruby DBI is unrelated to either of those — except to the extent they all provide access to databases.  They are completely separate — the same as JDBC and ODBC are completely separate (for Java and C respectively), even though they both provide access to databases.  There is likely more commonality between JDBC and ODBC than between the various libraries/modules with DBI in the name.

Comment: Is the DBI used with Raku the same as for Perl?

Comment: @Laurel: I'm no expert on Raku, so I'm not sure, but I think not.  A Google search for `raku dbi` comes up with [DBIish](https://github.com/raku-community-modules/DBIish).  The README.md says: _The DBIish project provides a simple database interface for Raku.  It's not a port of the Perl 5 DBI and does not intend to become one._  There aren't many Raku-related tags here on SO.  It's not clear that a [tag:raku-dbiish] tag would be beneficial — creating that would be up to the people who frequent the [tag:raku] tag.